# Redis - ECONNREFUSED. Even though server is running

Tags: node.js, redis, hiredis

I already read all the other threads on stackoverflow about the ECONNREFUSED error but still nothing worked. 
Currently I am working on Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS

For tests I have this really simple code:

```
var redis = require("redis"),
    client = redis.createClient(6379,"127.0.0.1");

redis.debug_mode = true;

client.on("connect", function () {
    client.set("foo_rand000000000000", "some fantastic value");
});
```

But whenever I am starting it, all I get is the ECONNREFUSED error:

```
root@oncn05:~/ba# node test.js
hiredis parser not installed.
Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED

node.js:201
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
          ^
Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED
    at RedisClient.on_error (/root/ba/node_modules/redis/index.js:196:24)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/root/ba/node_modules/redis/index.js:106:14)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:67:17)
    at Array.0 (net.js:319:25)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:41)
root@oncn05:~/ba#
```

The thing is: It is no problem to connect to redis with `redis-cli`.

```
root@oncn05:~/ba# redis-cli
redis 127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Also the logs do not show anything suspicious.
Why is it even saying that the hiredis parser is not installed? I installed it with `npm install hiredis`. But even if i didn't. Where is it even used?

I appreciate every help.

Comment: do you get the same result when you don't pass connection parameters to `createClient`?

Comment: What does `sudo netstat -nlp4` show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: Thank you to everyone who read and/or answered my question.

Normally it makes no difference if you pass createClient these parameters, because 127.0.0.1:6379 is the default setting.

I recognized that I had an old node.js version (0.6.xx), so I decided to completly delete it and than reinstall it.

So, first I deleted node with the command `sudo apt-get remove nodejs`. Afterwards I installed the new version like it is stated here: [installing via package manager](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager)

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Now everything works as expected. I don't know why i didn't think of this earlier.

Comment: I have the same issue with  node v0.6.12

Comment: Crazy issue, but i was experiencing the same issue on v0.6.12!